# how to use gtk/pywebkitgtk in jython?

Tags: python, gtk, jython

In installed standalone jython on my ubuntu 12.04, run it, but if I try to `import gtk`, I get `no module named gtk` when in python console it works.

**Update:**

I have done

`>> sys.path.insert(1,"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0")`

and

`>> sys.path.insert(1,'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages")`

and now is is

```
    from glib._glib import *
ImportError: No module named _glib
```

when:

```
argon@vprime:/usr/lib/python2.7$ find | grep _glib
./dist-packages/gi/_glib
./dist-packages/gi/_glib/option.pyc
./dist-packages/gi/_glib/option.py
./dist-packages/gi/_glib/_glib.so
./dist-packages/gi/_glib/__init__.pyc
./dist-packages/gi/_glib/__init__.py
./dist-packages/glib/_glib.so
./dist-packages/twisted/internet/test/test_glibbase.pyc
./dist-packages/twisted/internet/test/test_glibbase.py
./dist-packages/twisted/internet/_glibbase.py
./dist-packages/twisted/internet/_glibbase.pyc
./dist-packages/_dbus_glib_bindings.so
```

so, `glib/_glib` is under `dist-packages` and I have no idea what is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all modules are compatible between Jython and CPython (the standard Python interpreter). In particular, modules that are compiled to native bytecode, generally written in C/++ (or with Cython), cannot be loaded in Java, because it uses its own Virtual Machine (JVM) which cannot understand native bytecode.

Many native/binary modules in CPython will have a name prefixed with an underscore, like _glib above.

You have at least two options:

- Use Jython and a Java GTK package.
- Use CPython, and if you need to talk to Java, use one of the packages that interface between CPython and the JVM (e.g. [jpype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net), [py4j](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/)).